# `Delete` key doesn't work on vim insert mode for deleting previously typed content

Tags: vim

I opened vim in my iterm2. Firstly, I typed something on insert mode, like

```
Hello
```

At this stage, if I didn't exit from insert mode, `delete` key works and can delete the whole word if I want.

If I quit insert mode, and open insert mode again, this `Hello` can't be removed by `delete` key. But the newly typed-in content can be removed.

I've renamed my .vimrc, problem still exits.

In the shell command-line, my `delete` key works well.

And I did some test on remote server through `iterm`, didn't encounter the same issue.

What could be the cause of this problem? How to fix it?

---

PS:
As I'm using macbook, the `delete` key is corresponding for  `backspace` in PC.

Answer (score 49):

Just put this to your .vimrc :

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Comment: Thanks a lot saving my time :)

Comment: @Gawain, can you please explain the solution? Thanks.

Comment: What is a ".vimrc"? Is there a filepath for this?

Comment: @JohnSmith ".vimrc" file is in your home directory.

Comment: @JohnSmith edit: `vim ~/.vimrc`

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Pressing the `Delete` key under Ubuntu gets me out of INSERT mode and inserts the letter "D".

Answer (score 12):

Check for the `iTerm` key mappings (`Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys`). I was using the default Natural Text Editing preset, and by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351434/289949), deleting the key mappings related to delete solve the issue for me.

Comment: This was the problem on my case 

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case, I only needed to remove a single key mapping, namely the one for "Del→".

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing to do with the shell, or with the version of `vim`.  It's a simple configuration thing, as the operation of backspace in insert mode is ordinary `vim` configurable behaviour.  Specifically, it is `vim`'s `backspace` setting.  On one machine you (most probably) have that set to the empty string, and on another you have it set to include the value `start`.  And this is probably in a global configuration file.

Note that the default if you bring up `vim` in `vi`-compatible mode is for the `backspace` variable to be the empty string.  The behaviour that you are complaining about is in fact the behaviour of the original `vi`.  Linux operating systems tend to fill the global configuration file with all sorts of `vim` options that turn on "friendlier" behaviours that deviate from that of original `vi`.  The BSDs tend not to.

### Further reading

- Arnold Robbins, Elbert Hannah, and Linda Lamb (2008).  "Simple Editing".  *Learning the vi and Vim Editors*.  O'Reilly Media, Inc.. ISBN 9781449313258. p. 14.
- [`:help backspace`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backspace%27).  vim documentation.
- [Bug #19903](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=19903).  1998.  Debian BTS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might due to the version of vim installed on OSX by default.  You can always install vim via homebrew and see if that replacement helps. I found this page that kind of helps supe up the OSX terminal experience.
https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Take note of this line 'brew install vim --override-system-vi'